# Using logstash index in SIEM

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am using beats -> kafka streams -> logstash -> elsticsearch -> kibana.
Is it possible to use my new index to work in Security SIEM?
My logstash configuration:

```
input {
 kafka {
  bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
  topics => "apache"
 }
}
filter {
date {
match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}

}
output {
 elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
 }
}
```

Comment: This should work without ay issue, what is the question you have?

Comment: How can I add a logstash pattern to SIEM security?

Comment: the first best practice is to ensure a usage of ECS standard

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/security/7.10/ingest-data.html